# My Dell Venue 11 Pro loses the touch screen

Tags: windows-8.1, touchscreen, dell-venue

My Dell Venue 11 Pro loses contact with the touch screen from time to time. I can pop it onto the keyboard and continue working, but the only way to get touch back is to completely recycle the power.  Very annoying. I'll go dig through Device manager and the event viewer to see if anything obvious is happening, and whether there's a service I can recycle to get touch back, but does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was addressed in a new firmware and driver issue in February of this year.  I can't find the exact article which told me this, but I had to patch a friends Venue11 and it fixed it.

Alternatively, there are a couple of other things you can try:

1)Warranty - Venue11s are fairly new and most are still in warranty - Dell will replace the device if they cannot identify the problem immediately.

2)Services.  Take a look at services.msc for any services with the start type "auto" and the state "stopped" next time it crashes.  This will help you identify any potentially halting services.

3)Reinstall chipset, touchscreen, bios and video drivers - always a good idea with this type of problem.

4)system restore to a time when you know this was working

5)windows updates - there could be a newer signed driver, service update or other patch out there to help fix this issue

6)AV/AS scanning - if something is maliciously killing your touch screen interface - a good AV scanner will find it.

Hope one of these helps.